# how can I multipy an $m \times n$ matrix to make the 2nd row negative?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix:

$3 \times 3$ matrix.

Is there another matrix that I can multiply it by to make the 2nd column negative? And in general is there a rule for making a specific column of a matrix negative by multiplication?

Thank you

Comment: Multiply on the left or on the right?

Comment: sorry on the right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$, you can negate its second column and keep the others the same by multiplying by the matrix $N$ *on the right* $$N = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 &0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

That is, the matrix $MN$ has the same first and third columns as $M$ but the middle column is negated.  You can negate other columns by changing which entry on the diagonal of $N$ is -1.

Comment: Thanks so much @orlandpm